# Tool in .NET with source code to create and manipulate xml file

Tags: asp.net

I want a web application in ASP.NET(any version below VS 2010) in which i can create a xml file and edit its node and enter values and save that modified xml.

Somewhat similar to the tool found at below link:

http://finaldownload.com/components_libraries_xml_viewer-23601-download.html

Comment: You want to create or you want to have one that can do that ? If you want to find one, search the web...

Comment: I want to create but if the application is already there built in .net with the source code for ready to use then I don't find the need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin XMLReader/XMLWriter in .NET.

Examples:

- http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2009030701&page=1
- http://www.xmlplease.com/create-xml-writer
- https://web.archive.org/web/20210323155432/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092403-1.aspx
- http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+read+write+xml

Comment: Hi Josaph,

I want a web application with source code if ready similar to the tool (link provided), the tool is very handy.

We can create element by just right clicking on the node and then its child  , its attribute , values blah blah. Please see the tool for better understanding.